# I need to find tags in tags, selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to find certain links on the page, but there is no class or id in the "a" tags. But there is "span" with classes "ipsContained ipsType_break". I would like it to find all "span" first, and then "a" tags in them. Who knows tell me this or a simpler option

I use selenium, here's a sample html that includes links to fetch.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="./interference.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span class = "ipsContained ipsType_break">
    <a href="link1"></a>
    <a href="link2"></a>
  </span>
  <span class = "ipsContained ipsType_break">
    <a href="link3"></a>
    <a href="link4"></a>
  </span>
</body
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Selenium-based solution:**

you can construct an xpath for span tag like this:

```
//span[@class='ipsContained ipsType_break']
```

you can store them in a `list` and then you can get all the child `a tags` using `.`
and then link using `get_attribute` method.

**Code:**

```
spans =  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='ipsContained ipsType_break']")
a_tag_list = []
for span in spans:
    atag = span.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//a")
    print(atag.get_attribute('href'))
    a_tag_list.append(atag.get_attribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I use BeautifulSoup to parse html.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="./interference.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span class = "ipsContained ipsType_break">
    <a href="link1"></a>
    <a href="link2"></a>
  </span>
  <span class = "ipsContained ipsType_break">
    <a href="link3"></a>
    <a href="link4"></a>
  </span>
</body
</html>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
spans = soup.findAll("span", {"class":"ipsContained ipsType_break"})
links = []
for span in spans:
    aElements = span.findAll("a", href=True)
    for a in aElements:
        links.append(a["href"])
print(links)
```

Prints: `['link1', 'link2', 'link3', 'link4']`

Answer (score 0):

```
links=[x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//span[@class='ipsContained ipsType_break']//a")]
```

Should get you all the href links for every a tag inside those span class. Another approach other then appending to another list.